# Whats the proper way to flag a thread to exit using boost without c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

After reading various answers on how volatile should not be used to flag a running thread to exit, (And the suggestions to use `boost:atomic<>`) I still cannot find an answer on how to properly do this using boost without C++11.

1. Should I use `boost::mutex`?
2. If so, do I need to lock on my `m_stopThread` variable where I change it to true and in my run loop where I check it?
3. Is `boost::mutex` lock call going to make a call into the operating system or is it lighter just using memory barriers instructions etc.?

Comment: What's wrong with `interrupt`?

Comment: Mutex implementations vary, but e.g. Linux has `futex` ("Fast Userspace muTEX"), which is designed to avoid system calls unless the lock is actually contended. AFAIK all Linux synchronization primitives use this where possible, so `boost::mutex` on Linux should have the same property. `boost::mutex` on Windows probably uses `CriticalSection` where possible, for the same reason, but you'd have to check.

Comment: Oh, and system calls when the lock is contended "don't matter", because when acquiring the lock you're going to sleep or otherwise idle anyway and so you "can afford" them. When releasing the lock, OK, it does cost something when you have to make a system call to wake someone else up. But in practice most locks don't experience a lot of contention, so the occasional performance hit doesn't matter unless in an aggressively realtime context.

Comment: From the practical viewpoint simple volatile flag works ok. From the theoretical viewpoint why not to use c++11 ?

Comment: @user396672: The issue (that might depend on your actual code) is that the compiler can reorder access to non-volatile variables. If your only interaction between the two threads is a boolean flag, then the lack of a stricter guarantee probably won't matter, but if there is any other data exchange (consider updating a value in a publisher and notifying the consumer through a volatile flag) the ordering of the publishing with respect to the notification is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is only necessary to call something to issue write mamory barrier after setting and read memory barrier before testing. It may be atomic operation, mutex access or anything else.
(I suppose that even entering different mutexes will be Ok :)
If you don't hurry, you may do nothing, because the right barrier  instruction should be issued somewhen in the future (at least when hardware interrupt occurs).
Of course, m_stopThread should be declared volatile

(Although I may be wrong from the Stadard viewpoint)